# Interaction has already been acknowledged Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This command keeps on returning `Interaction has already been acknowledged`. How can I solve this?

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    EmbedBuilder,
    ButtonStyle,
    ButtonBuilder,
    ActionRowBuilder,
    ActionRow,
} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("highlow")
        .setDescription(" | Starts a new high or low game!"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        const hintNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setLabel("High")
                .setStyle("Secondary")
                .setCustomId("high"),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("low")
                .setLabel("Low")
                .setStyle("Secondary"),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("correct")
                .setLabel("Same")
                .setStyle("Secondary")
        );
        const sent = await interaction.reply({
            content: `Is my number higher or lower than ${hintNumber}?`,
            components: [row],
            fetchReply: true,
        });
        const collector = sent.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filter: (i) =>
                i.user.id === interaction.user.id && i.message.id === sent.id,
            time: 30000,
            max: 1,
        });
        let won = false;
        collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
            await i.deferUpdate({ fetchReply: true });
            row.components.forEach((b) => b.setDisabled(true));
            if (i.customId === "high") {
                if (hintNumber > randomNumber) {
                    row.components.forEach((b) => {
                        if (b.customId === "high") b.setStyle("Danger");
                    });
                    await interaction.editReply({
                        content: `Sadge, you got it wrong! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                        components: [row],
                    });
                    won = false;
                } else {
                    row.components.forEach((b) => {
                        if (b.customId === "high") b.setStyle("Success");
                    });
                    await interaction.editReply({
                        content: `You guessed the number! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                        components: [row],
                    });
                    won = true;
                }
            } else if (i.customId === "low") {
                if (hintNumber < randomNumber) {
                    row.components.forEach((b) => {
                        if (b.customId === "low") b.setStyle("Danger");
                    });
                    await interaction.editReply({
                        content: `Sadge, you got it wrong! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                        components: [row],
                    });
                    won = false;
                } else {
                    row.components.forEach((b) => {
                        if (b.customId === "low") b.setStyle("Success");
                    });
                    await interaction.editReply({
                        content: `You are right! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                        components: [row],
                    });
                    won = true;
                }
            } else if (i.customId === "correct" && hintNumber === randomNumber) {
                row.components.forEach((b) => {
                    if (b.customId === "correct") b.setStyle("Success");
                });
                await interaction.editReply({
                    content: `You guessed the number! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                    components: [row],
                });
                won = true;
            } else {
                await interaction.editReply({
                    content: `Sadge, you got it wrong! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                    components: [row],
                });
                won = false;
            }
        });
        collector.on("end", async (collected) => {
            row.components.forEach((b) => b.setDisabled(true));
            if (!won && collected.size === 0) {
                await interaction.editReply({
                    content: `You didn't guess the number! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                    components: [row],
                });
            }
        });
    },
};
```

The error is showing:

```
C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Ayanokoji\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293
        throw new DiscordAPIError.DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Ayanokoji\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Ayanokoji\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Ayanokoji\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22) 
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Ayanokoji\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:192:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Documents\Ayanokoji\interactions\slash\fun\highlow.js:44:4) {
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1021755660406374452/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTAyMTc1NTY2MDQwNjM3NDQ1MjpyMjViUU8xSGtzQ1dXZXVXbWh2YmRiczZ5ZldzcVhuYm1hNXdWWFRRSVlUUzk0MXFDV1M2NmRjQWF3MEJXTVo0TmN1UlR3U1QxQnUxVDd1YlZodjdnbnpNRVM5VlVSV1B0aUNSS2ZGZkQ5QURrdlFIenVHaUVZdTRkUmR5YnBVaQ/callback',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 6 } }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 44: `await i.deferUpdate({ fetchReply: true });` It makes the error because the interaction has already been replied to. The error should go away when you remove this line. You also should replace `await interaction.editReply` with `interaction.followUp` on line 51, 60, 71, 80, 90, 96 and 106. And yup I answer your question again.